# Sublime Text Side Panel

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I don't have a coding problem yet, I would like to ask before I start.
I have really huge configuration files, custom syntax highlighting and auto-complete plugin will be sure feasible. But, I would need side panel with tree structure, would it be possible with Sublime Text?

The structure is similar to this:
[/abc]
params...
[/abc/efg]
params...
[/abc/efg/xxx]
params...
[/abc/xxx]
params...

So I need a tree with ability to collapse sections. Any suggestions?

Best regards
David

Answer (score 1):

There are many plugins available for custom syntax highlighting in sublime text or you can install some with package manager in sublime text.
First, install package control from sublime text menu  `tools→ install package control` you can now go to `preference→package control →install package` and install your desired package if you found or else you can try searching the plugin in the github repositories.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my question is in fact about the side panel (or navigation pane), which would display stanzas as a tree - similar like directory structure, but for stanzas in config file.

I can try and develop such functionality, but I need to know if it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

For adding side panel, go to view -> side bar -> show side bar. This will add the side bar which is the file tree structure of your project.